# Instagram Content Publishing API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to set schedule publish time and draft on an instagram post with api ?.

My current application of the api :

```
    $params = [
        'image_url'=>'url',
        'caption'=> '#test',
    ];

    $containerId = $service->params($params)->post()->json()
```

which returns an id of the IG Container which can be published after.

I have tried reading the Meta Documentation but there is not much to find.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram's Graph API for content publishing does not support scheduling posts or setting draft status directly through the API. The API primarily focuses on immediate post creation and publishing.

However, since you can post through the API, you can set up the scheduler on your side to call the post endpoint at a certain time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).